# Vlookup in Visual Basic: Trying to Set for the reference column that has a variable range

Tags: excel, vba

I had a question regarding the code below.  If anyone could provide some insight, I would be greatly appreciative.  Essentially this is part of a report I'm building to be run on a weekly basis.  The issue I'm having is that the reference column K is variable in size of inputs and I hate putting in a constant that results in a bunch of N/A#s (K rows should never exceed 300).  I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking, but I tried to write something to count K2:Kn and then input it in the Ranges (q2:r2:s2:t2:qrstn).  Please share your wisdom =)

```
Sub Vlookup()
    Sheets(2).Select
    Range("q2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],table,15,FALSE)"
    Range("q2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("q2:q300"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("r2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-7],table,16,FALSE)"
    Range("r2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("r2:r300"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("s2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-8],table,17,FALSE)"
    Range("s2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("s2:s300"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("t2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-9],table,18,FALSE)"
    Range("t2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("t2:t300"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope I've understood your question properly

The following will autofill range `Q2:QN` where N is the last used cell in column Q

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range("K2"),Range("K2").End(xlDown)).Offset(ColumnOffset:=6), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

You could also do it the other way round as you have a fixed maximum.

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range("K2"),Range("K301").End(xlUp)).Offset(ColumnOffset:=6), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

The first looks down the sheet for the last row, and the 2nd looks up the sheet from the maximum to the last row.

You can replace Q with whatever column you need, as you appear do do the same for lots of columns!

**Update**

I've updated the example, it now finds the used range in the K column and offsets it to your desired column. The value of `ColumnOffset` will be the same (although positive) as the value used in your `R1C1` formulas.

Also, as the K Range should remain constant, and your formulas are fairly predictable you could shorten it a little. like the following (i've not testing it, just playing around)

```
Sub Vlookup() ' might want to re-name, to avoid confusion with the worksheet function
Dim R As Range
Dim A As Range
Dim I As Integer

  Set R = Range(Range("K2"), Range("K301").End(xlUp))
  Set A = Range("K2")

  For I = 6 To 9
    A.Offset(ColumnOffset:=I).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-" & CStr(I) & "], table, " & CStr(I+9) & ", FALSE)"
    A.Offset(ColumnOffset:=I).AutoFill Destination:=R.Offset(I), Type:=xlFillDefault
  Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: Whoops, I did get it wrong. Forgot to actually use the reference column. Ill try again.

Comment: Hi Nick:  Thank you for your help this far.  I could not get this to work.  Essentially I have Column K, in this we'll call it Purchase Orders.  Essentially there is another data sheet that has 4 other columns that I need and shares Purchase Orders as a point which you can essentially do a join.  The problem I'm facing is that column K varies report to report.  I know that PO's will never be > 300 but I would love if it would look at column K count the number of records and then input the number into vlookup function (vlookup (k2,table,?,false).  I really appreciate everything =)

Comment: I think all you need then is `Range(Range('K2'),Range('K301').End(xlUp).Rows.Count `. You can store it in a `Long` or `Integer` as its <300 and then reference it in your lookup

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to fill down when you use FormulaR1C1.  You can apply the formula to the whole range.  Here's an example.

```
Sub MakeVlookup()

    Dim lRows As Long, lCols As Long
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRef As Range

    'Set the first cell of the reference column
    Set rRef = Sheet1.Range("K2")

    'Count the rows of the reference column
    lRows = Sheet1.Range(rRef, rRef.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    'Loop through the row 2 cells where you want the formula
    For Each rCell In Sheet1.Range("Q2:T2").Cells
        'Compute the offset back to the reference column
        lCols = rCell.Column - rRef.Column
        'Write the formula to the whole range
        rCell.Resize(lRows, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=VLOOKUP(RC[-" & lCols & "],Table1," & rCell.Column - 2 & ",FALSE)"
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to loop or address each column with a different formula!

Instead of these formulas:

```
Column Q: =VLOOKUP(K2,table,15,FALSE)
Column R: =VLOOKUP(K2,table,16,FALSE)
...
```

you can simply use

```
=VLOOKUP($K2,table,COLUMN()-2,0)
```

as one formula across all columns! `$K2` (in R1C1: `RC11`) instead of `K2` (in R1C1 `RC[-6]`, `RC[-7]`, ...) will keep column K. And `COLUMN()` will return you the column number of the actual cell, i.e. column Q = 17, R = 18, etc.. (I also replaced `FALSE` with `0` as this reduces typing for lazy blokes like me but results in the same. :-) ).

Therefore, you can reduce your macro to

```
Sub MakeVLOOKUP
    Sheets(2).Range("Q2:T300").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC11,table,COLUMN()-2,0)"
End Sub
```

and achieve the same result.

If you want to flexibilize the range as in Dick's solution, you can do it like this:

```
Sub MakeVLOOKUP
    Sheets(2).Range("Q2").Resize(Sheet1.Range("K2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count-1,4).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC11,table,COLUMN()-2,0)"
End Sub
```